# JavaScript Search over HTML DOM not working while typing fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented a simple javascript search over the elements in my HTML page.
Everything works fine except when I type fast search code is hiding every element in DOM and showing nothing. this is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObvPmw

As an example search for word `lorem` first slowly and then fast. When we search fast entire elements will go off.
Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i looked into your code. As you are using keyup event for calling doSearch function, meanwhile you are using fadeIn function for hiding/showing data.I would like to illustrate the problem with an example, when you type any character it hides all the text (for a very little span of time) and then shows the results (based on doSearch function). So, when you type fast it calls doSearch function everytime key is up and hence it calls doSearch function on empty text (as the results are not returned by previous call i-e text is still hidden). Maybe you need to bind your doSearch function with some kind of restriction that until the text is not shown it wouldn't be called.

Edit: just change the lines:
           CharityNames.parents("li").fadeIn();
           CharityText.parents("li").fadeIn(); 
      to
           CharityNames.parents("li").show();
           CharityText.parents("li").show();

and it will work fine. But i dont know if it is your requirement to fadeIn the text.

Comment: @Athul Junaid Ahmad __did__ suggest a proper answer, an the corresponding code __is__ in its answer! I just tested it in your http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObvPmw and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a suggestion and not the solution to you problem asking why your code is not working as you expect.

Your logic looks little complicated and too many function calls which will reduce the performance.

If interested, Here is a small sample which does exactly what you need. **[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/4hm0mgzy/2/)**

```
//This is a extension to do case insensitive search. Extension Name "containsCIn"
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  'containsCIn': function(elem, i, match, array) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
      .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }
});

// this is the sample code which filters the content on search string
$(function() {
  $('#txtesearch').on('keyup', function() {
    var searchtext = $(this).val();

    $('ul.charity-listing, ul.charity-listing li').hide();
    $('ul.charity-listing li:containsCIn("' + searchtext + '")').show();   

    $('ul.charity-listing').fadeIn({duration: 200}); // default is 400, i reduced the time to make it render fast.
  });
});
```